# How to use function computed to display variable in vue template + laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, variables, vue.js

I want to display the variable from the database and round it before. Can you help me about syntax for this.

```
<h2 class="txt-bold">Rating: {{roundHalf(ListOrg.rating)}}</h2>


computed: {
    roundHalf: function(num) {
      return Math.round(num * 2) / 2;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you want to pass a parameter, then it becomes a method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use computed value :

```
<h2 class="txt-bold">Rating: {{roundHalf}}</h2>


computed: {
    roundHalf: function() {
      return Math.round(this.ListOrg.rating * 2) / 2;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use Vue filter :

Define a filter : (Global filter)

```
Vue.filter('roundHalf', function (value) {
    return Math.round(value * 2) / 2;
})
```

And use in vue file like :

```
<h2 class="txt-bold">Rating: {{ListOrg.rating | roundHalf}}</h2>
```

Defining a global filter will help you use it everywhere in the project. :)

Reference :
[Vue Filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)